# ActiveMQ 5.10 Producer Flow Control with Non-Persistent Topics

Tags: java, activemq-classic, middleware

I am trying to test producer flow control with non-persistent topics for activemq 5.10. I have disabled producer flow control and want to see whether System usage flow control will kick in when system usage limits are reached.

But even when persistent store is used 100% then also producer is not stopped from publishing.

What can be the possible reason?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a consumer on the other end?  Are there durable subscriptions?  What are the conditions of the test, without those no answer is possible.

Comment: I tried with and without consumer. When I used consumer I make durable subscription and then closed consumer so that its message will remain with broker.

Comment: @TimBish can you please guide me on how to test these features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first understand the [difference](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Factivemq.apache.org%2Fhow-does-a-queue-compare-to-a-topic.html&ei=ENUFVIGLFIjzgwT584LgCw&usg=AFQjCNEjtSeMQM9El6vcIMUYp-Susf5VMQ&sig2=vXgqaAoufEB5Qr0Z17XLVA&bvm=bv.74115972,d.eXY) between Topics and Queues.  For a normal topic with no consumers no messages are retained, they just get tossed out as the publish subscribe model only cares about connected consumers.  Even when you send a messages as persistent it's meaningless as the Topic does not persist messages unless there is a registered durable consumer that is offline.

In the case of the offline durable consumer there would be no producer flow control until such time as you hit the store limit as messages are written to disk and not stored in memory.

Comment: Lets say I have a durable subscriber and I sent message with persistent flag set to false (i.e., none persistent durable messages on a topic) and producer flow control set to false. Now will broker stop producer to send messages onto this topic if memory limit of producer reaches ? Will it stop it if temporary storage limit will reach?

Comment: With producer flow control disabled, all bets are off.

Comment: so when system usage are done i.e., no more space to store those messages, there is no concept of durability producer will send messages which will be dumped immediately?

Comment: You should start seeing resource allocation errors being propagated back to the client from the broker.